# When querying for a single item in graphql, meteor, and apollo i get null values returned

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo

I have probably overlooked something in the docs, but I have seem to run into a problem with being able to get a single object from my graphql queries.

Here is the schema:

```
type Query {
    product(name: String!): Product
}

type Product {
    _id: String
    name: String
}
```

Here is the resolver:

```
Query: {
   product (_, args) {
       return Products.find({where: args})
   },
   products () {
       return Products.find().fetch()
   }
}
```

Here is the Query:

```
query {
    product(name: "burgers") {
        name
    }
}
```

I get a result of this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "product": {
          "name": null
        }
    }
}
```

Am I just forgetting to add something to this, and if so could you point me the right direction.

Comment: What does your data look like? When  you say you get null values returned, does it return rows with null values?

Comment: I get the result provided on the last code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Products` is a Meteor Collection, then `.find` returns a cursor, so the right thing to return would be `Products.findOne({name: args.name})`

http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne